# Asciidoc and math equation does not render on .docx

Tags: docx, doc, pandoc, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm trying to convert .adoc files to .docx

Actually I'm using:

```
asciidoctor file.adoc -o file.html
pandoc -s -S file.html -o output.docx
```

My math equations or symbols inside .adoc are equal to:

```
latexmath:[$\phi$] and more text as Inline test latexmath:[$\sin(x)$]
```

It returns after conversion to docx the strange lines inside .docx:

```
\($\phi$\) and more text as Inline test \($\sin(x)$\)
```

Any hint?

```
$ pandoc --version
pandoc 1.13.2.1
Compiled with texmath 0.8.2, highlighting-kate 0.5.15.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly enable the `tex_math_dollars` extension with html input:

```
pandoc -s -S file.html -f html+tex_math_dollars -o output.docx
```

And sed can deal with the remaining escaped parenthesis (`\(`) :

```
asciidoctor file.adoc -o file.html
sed -r 's/\\\(/\(/g' < file.html | sed -r 's/\\\)/\)/g' > file2.html
pandoc -s -S file2.html -f html+tex_math_dollars -o output.docx
```

Comment: Nice!! It's a progress. But it renders the Formulas with " \ ( " before and after LaTeX stuff.

Comment: @arnaldo I don't use asciidoc but I might be able to help on the html to docx conversion if you add the output of `asciidoctor file.adoc -o file.html`

Comment: Thanks @scoa! Follows the HTML generated by asciidoc. http://pastebin.com/9t1RD9U1

Comment: @arnaldo isn't there something in your original asciidoc that causes this? If I compile this file :  `($C_y / C_x = \frac{Z_x - G}{Z_x}$)     (Eq. 1)` with ` asciidoctor input.adoc -o temp.html ; pandoc -s -S temp.html -o output_from_adoc.docx -f html+tex_math_dollars`, it works fine.

Comment: Hi @scoa, You are right, if I include directly the equation inside Dollars, it render the right equation inside my docx, but it fails to generate the right equation symbols to .tex and also .pdf. I was including equations as referenced at AciiDoc manual (e.g. latexmath:[$C_y / C_x = \frac{Z_x - G}{Z_x}$]. By the way, my toolchain is generate .html from asciidoc, after .xml (docbook) and using dblatex to convert to pdf. Any trick to fix both converters?

Comment: @arnaldo In that case, I would just preprocess the html file, in between the asciidoctor and the pandoc command to remove escaped parenthesis : `sed -r 's/\\\(/\(/g' < file.html | sed -r 's/\\\)/\)/g' > file2.html` Unless you really need escaped parenthesis somewhere in the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot @scoa!! Sometimes I think is really tricky to write with AsciiDoctor, or to be obligated to deal with multiple extension files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77048/discussion-between-arnaldo-and-scoa).